# Colliding regex for emails (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to grab both usernames (such as abc123@) and emails (such as (abc123@company.com) in the same Pythonic regex.

Here's an example statement:

`abc123@ is a researcher at abc123@company.com doing cool work.`

Regex used:

For username:

`re.match("^([A-Za-z])+([@]){1}$")`

For email:

`re.match("^([A-Za-z0-9-_])+(@company.com){1}$")`

Most cases, what happens is username gets grabbed but not email address (trying to grab them as two separate entities) - any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Do you want **ONE** regex that will capture both `abc123@` and `abc123@company,com`? If yes, it is not clear why you have mentioned 2 regexes here.

Comment: I want 2 separate regexes - because I am trying to find two separate entities (emails and usernames)

Comment: One that finds only abc123@ and one that finds only abc123@company.com where abc123 could be anything like xyz8494 or asda92340 for example

Comment: For email, you can use something like this `re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@company\.com$")`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a lot of groups and repetition counts and start/end boundaries in your regexes that are not really necessary. These 2 are just enough to find each in the input string.

For user: `[A-Za-z0-9]+@`

For email: `[A-Za-z0-9-_]+@company.com`

If, however, you want your groupings, these versions that will work:

For user: `([A-Za-z0-9])+(@)`

For email: `([A-Za-z0-9-_]+(@company.com)`

**Disclaimer:** I have tested this only on Java, as I am not so familiar with Python.

Comment: an email address can also contain the `+` sign

Comment: @jmunsch, I am going by the posted requirement, which doesn't have it. Even the regex @mike0494 has tried uses `+` only meaning `one or more`, not as part of the email.

Comment: ah okay. just figured i'd mention it. also this was interesting : https://www.emailregex.com/

Answer (score 0):

In your patterns you use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and end of the string.

Removing the anchors, will leave this for the username pattern `([A-Za-z])+([@]){1}`

Here, you can omit the `{1}` and the capture groups. Note that in the example, `abc123@` has digits that you are not matching.

Still, using `[A-Za-z0-9]+@` will get a partial match in the email `abc123@company.com` To prevent that, you can use a right hand whitespace boundary.

The username pattern might look like

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9]+@(?!\S)
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of the listed (including the digits)
- `@` Match literally
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert not a non whitspace char to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vv5K8/1)

For the email address, using a character class like `[A-Za-z0-9-_]` is quite strict.

If you want a broad match, you might use:

```
[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EaOqU0/1)

Comment: It was a very restricted format. what regex can you write for following question?
https://github.com/NaiveNeuron/nlp-exercises/blob/master/ex1-regex/regex.ipynb